# JQuery Isotope with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, jquery-isotope

I am developing SPA nowadays and do not know how to use isotope -*metafizzy*- in AngularJS. I searched a lot and found some trivia but not compatible with the new version of angular and isotope.

Below is the HTML side:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box app-box" ng-repeat="app in apps">
    <div class="app-name">{{app.ApplicationName}}</div>
    <div class="last-update">{{app.LastUpdate}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript side that isotope is set in.

```
var $grid = $(".grid");
var options = {
  itemSelector: ".app-box",
  layoutMode: "masonry",
  filter: "*"
};

$grid.isotope(options);
```

This JavaScript code is located at the bottom of the above HTML page. And it's a partial view. When you go to `/home` route, it renders that view.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: No friend, still there is no solution